# PHP generated Excel sheet creates duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to generate a report to an excel sheet in my PHP web application. So far I was able to generate a report on an excel sheet. However, what I am facing now is I have duplicate entries on my excel sheet. My report is about a Lecture attendance sheet. It holds lectures work related to one course. My current problem is when a lecture has two or more rows printed on the excel sheet it will duplicate the "Hours Assigned" with the rows. For example, if we have two rows on my table it will show two hours assigned. What I want is to print "Hours assigned only once" No matter if I have 2 or more rows on the table hrs should only Come once. I will attach two photos one is with a one-row other one is with two rows.

[image: Only one row][image: With three rows and duplicte hours assined]

Here is my Code

````
`` `$query = "select * from t_time t, c_assign c where t.le_name like '$lec22' and t.co_name like '$course22' and t.rdate BETWEEN '" . $mydate2 . "' AND  '" . $mydate1 . "' and t.approval='Approved' and t.co_name=c.c_name"; ``
`//$query = "select c.* from c_assign c where c.tot_hr, c.nic,c.c_name,c.rate,c.id,l.f_name as first, l.l_name as last from c_assign c, lecture_reg l where c.nic=l.nic");`
`$result = $con->query( $query );`

`$num_results = $result->num_rows;`
`$remainingBal=0;`
`$totIns1 = 0;`
`$totIns2 = 0;`
`$totIns3 = 0;`

```
if($lec22=='%' || $course22=='%' || $mydate3=='')
{

  echo "<script>alert('All the fields are required!!!'); window.location.href = '../Lecture/attendance_sheet.php'; </script>";
}


else if( $num_results > 0)
{ 
  
  
  while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    
    extract($row);
    $hourstot = floor($tot_hr / 3600);
    $minutestot = floatval(($tot_hr / 60) % 60);
    
echo "<h4 class='text-muted font-15 m-b-15'>  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<b>* Hours Assigned : $hourstot : $minutestot  </b></h4>";
echo "<h4 class='text-muted font-15 m-b-15'>  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<b>----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- </b></h4>";
            echo "</tr>";
$hours = floor($to_time / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($to_time / 60) % 60);

//  $hourstot = floor($tot_hr / 3600);
//  $minutestot = floor(($tot_hr / 60) % 60);
echo "<tr>";


echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td>{$rdate}</td>";
echo "<td>{$s_time}</td>";
echo "<td>{$e_time}</td>";
echo "<td>$hours h : $minutes m  </td>";
echo "<td>{$coverage}</td>";
// echo "<td>".$sql_fetch['rate']."</td>";
//  echo "<td>$hourstot : $minutestot </td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "</tr>";
````

What I want is to print "Hours assigned only once". No matter I have 2 or more rows on the table hrs should only occur once. I will attach two photos one is with a one row other one is with two rows.

Comment: Where’s the screenshot with results?

Comment: This code looks severely trashed in terms of formatting. Tip: Indent with four spaces, or mark off the code block using three "backtick" characters at the start and end.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the following code out from the while loop will work.

```
 $hourstot = floor($tot_hr / 3600);
 $minutestot = floatval(($tot_hr / 60) % 60);
```